# authenticate() not working properly for django

Tags: python, django

Basically what I have done so far is create a registration page where the user makes their username and password, then that password is stored in as a hashed password (md5 hasher). The problem I am having is logging in. The user inputs their username and password then the password is authenticated by using authenticate() method in django. The problem is that authenticate() is returning None instead of matching the user and password in the database. I dont know if this affects anything but I am using PostgreSQL.

models.py

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email,username,first_name,password= None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User must have an email address')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('User must have a username')
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError('User must have a first name')
        user= self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username= username,
            first_name= first_name
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_superuser(self, email, username, first_name, password):
        user= self.create_user(
            email= self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            first_name= first_name,
            password= password,
        )
        user.is_admin= True
        user.is_staff= True
        user.is_superuser= True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
class User(AbstractBaseUser, models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='date joined')
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    USERNAME_FIELD= 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS= ['email','first_name']
    
    objects= MyAccountManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

forms.py

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(initial='' ,label='Username:',max_length=30)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password')
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(LoginForm, self).clean()
        confirm_password = cleaned_data.get('password')



class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(required= True,initial='',max_length=20)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=30, initial='')
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30,initial='', required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length= 20, initial='', widget = forms.PasswordInput())
    password2= forms.CharField(max_length=20, initial='',widget = forms.PasswordInput())
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=60, initial='',)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name','username','password2','email')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(SignUpForm,self).clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get('password')
        confirm_password = cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if(password != confirm_password):
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                'Password and Confirm Password do not match.'
            )
```

views.py

```
def signin_and_signup(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        logout(request)
        sign_in = LoginForm(request.POST)
        signup = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if 'sign-in-name' in request.POST:
            if sign_in.is_valid():
                username = request.POST.get('username')
                password= request.POST.get('password')
                user = authenticate(username= username, password= password)
                if user:
                    return HttpResponse('success')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('fail')
        elif 'sign-up-input-name' in request.POST:
            if(signup.is_valid()):
                user = signup.save(commit=False)
                nonHashed = signup.cleaned_data['password']
                varhash =  make_password(nonHashed, None, 'md5')
                user.set_password(varhash)
                user.save()

            else:
                print("Ran3<------------")
                signup = SignUpForm()
    else:
        sign_in = LoginForm()
        signup = SignUpForm()
    context = {'signin':sign_in, 'signup':signup}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you substituting the user model that django provides if you have the same attributes?
This is done in case you want to extend or add new properties to the user, for example, license number, avatar, position.

Anyway, your authenticate() maybe doesn't work because you haven't registered your new model in settings.py.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'name_of_the_app.User'
```

I recommend that you take a look at the official documentation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/

#### Antoher thing it could be your authentication backend:

Try:

settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'name_of_the_app.admin.LoginBackend',
]
```

Where you want for example admin.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend, UserModel
from django.db.models import Q


class LoginBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:  # to allow authentication through phone number or any other field, modify the below statement
            user = UserModel.objects.get(Q(username__iexact=username) | Q(email__iexact=username))
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            UserModel().set_password(password)
        except MultipleObjectsReturned:
            return models.User.objects.filter(email=username).order_by('id').first()
        else:
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user
    
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        return user if self.user_can_authenticate(user) else None
```

As you can see, you can also login with the email

Comment: I already have the AUTH_USER_MODEL in my settings.py that is why I am really confused

Comment: @kixsmart Check now with the authentication backend:

Comment: yeah man idk what the problem is nothing is working. Idk if this makes a difference but the password is hashed with md5